# What happen with mapstatetoprops in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

> this file index.js

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import rootReducers from './rootReducers'
const store = createStore(rootReducers)
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> this id file rootreducers.js

```
const todos = [
    { id: 1, name: "Khoa" },
    { id: 2, name: "Khoai" },
    { id: 3, name: "Kha" }
  ];
  const TodoList = (state = todos, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      default:
        return state
    }
  };
  export default TodoList;
```

> this is file list.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {connect } from "react-redux";

class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.todoList);

  }
};
mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todoList: state // err this code
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(List);
```

> i'm install react-redux and redux but when i write method mapstatetoprops it message : 'mapStateToProps' is not defined. help me.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to hard code selectors in mapStateToProps (ore callback to useSelector). Instead try to use reselect so you can compose selectors so you can define where certain information in state can be found and in what shape it should be returned once and have meoization as possible extra benifit. Some documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)

Answer (score 1):

mapStateToProps is simply an object. 
You need to initialize as a variable, preferably a const

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todoList: state // err this code
  };
};
```